# Azure Active Directory Windows authentication Fetch calendar events

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-3.1

I have created a project for .NET Core with Windows authentication. I want to get an idea about how to access the user calendar events. User will just access the website and then the user will be authenticated using windows authentication and his calendar data will be loaded on the homepage.

Any idea will be useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Users need to have **Calendars.Read, Calendars.ReadWrite** delegated Microsoft Graph permissions to access the user calendar events

You can assign this access in add API permissions

**Reference**: [Get calendar - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)